# Find the solution of $(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + 14y = 5x^3$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, legendre-polynomials

Find the solution of $$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + 14y = 5x^3.$$

There are no answers ( although I could substitute them), so I'd like to know if my general approach is correct:

1) I would find the solution to the homogeneous equation $$(1-x^2)y'' - 2xy' + 14y = 0$$ which has the solution of the Legendre polynomial with l = $\frac12 (-1 + \sqrt{57}).$ So it is a linear combination of the even and odd solutions.

2) For the inhomogenuous solutions, I took linear combinations of $P_1(x)$ and $P_3(x)$, which gives $$C_1(-2 + 14)x + C_2(-6 + 7)(5x^3 -x) = 5x^3$$.

The coefficient of $C_2$ is then $1$ and the coefficient of $C_1$ is $1/12$.

Is the approach correct?

Comment: Is there a typo in the second term of your question?

Comment: I can provide an alternate solution but not sure of your approach.

Comment: looks not bad to me

Comment: I would still appreciate an alternative method.